# How to extract Javascript variables from a script tag in a Scrapy response?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

```
<script type="text/javascript">

define('roomsAndRatesData', function() {
var roomsAndRatePlans = {"propertyData":{"bookingFeeMessageEnabled":true}},{"rooms":{"24-285501":{"locale":"en"}}}

};
</script>
```

There where other variable also define in that script. i just need data that are inside "var roomsAndRatePlans" variable can any one suggest solution to get only that variable data.

i have try other solutions but always retrieve all data inside that script tag and converting that data throws error.

so please provide me solution to get only particular data of that script

Thanks

Comment: You cannot retrieve it by XPath, you have to extract it by Regex.

Comment: Can you help me to create that Regex, as i don't have much idea about how to use Regex @thirdDeveloper

Comment: For me this looks like a nested dictionary. So try to separate the stuff after the = and then access like an dictionary

Comment: You can try using js2xml: https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [js2xml](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml) library:

```
>>> import js2xml
>>> from js2xml.utils.vars import get_vars
>>> snippet = '''
var product = {"price": 10.93, "stock": false, "name": "JBL"};
var analytics = {"id": 1234};
'''
>>> get_vars(js2xml.parse(snippet))
{
    'product': {'price': 10.93, 'stock': False, 'name': 'JBL'},
    'analytics': {'id': 1234}
}
```

Your JS snippet seems to be incomplete, so I used a dummy snippet here.
In your case, you may first have to get the JS code via:

```
>>> snippet = response.css('script:contains("roomsAndRatesData")::text').get()
```